# subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are not retracts of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology

I have to either prove or disprove: *There exist infinitely many subspaces (up to homeomorphism) of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are not retracts of $\mathbb{R}^2$.*

I can think of a few subspaces (e.g., finite sets) that are not retracts. A hint or two to get me going in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

W.

Comment: Finite subsets with $\ge 2$ are enough: there are infinitely many of those, up to bijection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $S^1\times \{1,2,\ldots, n\}\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ embedded by looking at the collections of circles of radius $1$ centered around say the first $n$ even natural numbers, i.e.

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: (x-2k)^2+(y-2k)^2=1\right\}$$ There is one for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Clearly they are not homeomorphic just by counting connected components, and none are retracts of $\Bbb R^2$, which is observable by checking the fundamental groups, which are $\Bbb Z$ (choose any base-point).

Your example of finite sets can work too, clearly

$$[n]=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$$

are all non-homeomorphic by counting connected components, but since the fundamental groups are trivial, it takes a bit more set theory to push things around to work, and you only get it for $n>1$, obviously, but that's not terrible either. Mostly you just say $\Bbb R^2\to [n]$ is necessarily constant because $\Bbb R^2$ is connected, then since retractions have left-inverses, by definition, you have

$$[n]\to \Bbb R^2\to [n]$$

is the identity, but this only works if $n=1$.

Comment: Why didn't you use the connectedness argument in the first example? A retract of $\Bbb R^2$ is always connected, isn't it?

Comment: I like the fundamental group. :-)

And moreover, it's usually a common invariant, and a good one to get into. Ultimately I chose based on homotopy properties, so I always have $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ in mind for simplicity, but they don't usually talk about $\pi_0$ at the point the op seems to be at, so I did it "by-hand" as it were.

Comment: @QuangHoang also, for $n=1$ in the first example, you cannot do that trick, the fundamental group captures **everything** for **all** of them, which I feel is cleaner than separate arguments or forcing $n\ge 2$ artificially.

Comment: My philosophy/approach is a little different. Connected components come way before $\pi_1$ in most courses. Also, I would attack this problem as: Points are obviously retract of $\Bbb R^2$. What are the next simplest subsets? Two-point set - Ding ding ding. Anyway, good examples.